# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, setstate

### I have Two dialog box here. when first one will close after that second one should be open but Here I am getting error.
This is working fine I am not using setState in PopUpBannerDialogPage, when using setState then getting error.

```
 showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: true,
            // barrierColor: MyColor.greyColor.withOpacity(0.4),
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return MpinSuccessDialogPage(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                image: "assets/unSuccess_icon.png",
                title: "No outlet is available nearby",
                subTitle:
                    "No outlet is available in your area right now. Spice up your search by trying another location or enjoy our takeaway option!",
              );
            }).then((value) {
          print("checkPopUpBannerCount$checkPopUpBannerCount");
          if (checkPopUpBannerCount == 0) {
            showDialog(
              // barrierDismissible: false,
              // barrierColor: MyColor.greyColor.withOpacity(0.4),
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return PopUpBannerDialogPage(); // Custom widget for the popup image
              },
            ).then((value) {
              print("This is PopUpBanner CallBack");
              checkPopUpBannerCount++;
              print(checkPopUpBannerCount);
            });
          }
        });
```

second dialog box

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import '../../BlocPages/CubitPage/BannerCubit/banner_cubit.dart';
import '../../BlocPages/CubitPage/BannerCubit/banner_state.dart';
import '../GlobalColor/global_color.dart';

class PopUpBannerDialogPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const PopUpBannerDialogPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<PopUpBannerDialogPage> createState() => _PopUpBannerDialogPageState();
}

class _PopUpBannerDialogPageState extends State<PopUpBannerDialogPage> {
  var loading;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: dialogContent(context),
    );
  }
}

extension widgetExtension on _PopUpBannerDialogPageState {
  dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<BannerCubit, BannerState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if(state is BannerCodeSentState){
        return BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.3, sigmaY: 3.3),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: loading != null ? 363 : null,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0,right: 8.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: MyColor.blackColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                        offset: const Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: MyColor.whiteColor,
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: MyColor.blackColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                          offset: const Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                              child: Image.network(
                                '${state.bannerModel.popupBanner}',
                                // height: 350,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                                    ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    loading = loadingProgress;
                                  });
                                  print("loadingProgress$loadingProgress");
                                  if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                                  return Container(
                                    height: 350,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator( color: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                                        value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                                            ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                            loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                                            : null,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },

                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
              Positioned(
                right: 0.0,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    print("Cancel");
                  },
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 14.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.close, color: MyColor.primaryRedColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      return Container();
    }
    );
  }
}
```